# datetime string throws ValueError

Tags: python, datetime

Input sample

```
Sun 10 May 2015 13:54:36 -0700
Sun 10 May 2015 13:54:36 -0000
Sat 02 May 2015 19:54:36 +0530
Fri 01 May 2015 13:54:36 -0000
```

According to this [Programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime) I used these directives as follows

`%a`    Abbreviated weekday name

`%d`    Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal

`%b`    Abbreviated month name

`%Y`    Year with century as a decimal number

`%H`    Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number

`%M`    Minute as a zero-padded decimal number

`%S`    Second as a zero-padded decimal number

`%z`    UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM.

```
from datetime import datetime 


def fun(t):
    d = datetime.strptime( '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %z' , t)
    print (d)

for i in range(4):
    fun(t=str(input()))
```

But I get the following error

```
ValueError: time data '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %z' does not match format 'Sun 10 May 2015 13:54:36 -0700'
```

Using python 3.6 and tried to replace the value of directives multiple times just can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

datetime.strptime 's 1st parameter should be a string and 2nd parameter is the format.

so your fun fucntion should be:

```
def fun(t):
    d = datetime.strptime(t, '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
    print (d)
```

Comment: ```  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    print (fun(t1=d1 , t2=d2))
  File "main.py", line 7, in fun
    d1 = datetime.strptime(t1, '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 365, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:``` 
I get this error

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments were not in the right order in `datetime.strptime()` :

```
def fun(t):
    d = datetime.strptime(t, '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
    print (d)

fun('Sun 10 May 2015 13:54:36 -0700')
```

gives : `2015-05-10 13:54:36-07:00`